# PHP Basic RESTFUL Web Service

Tags: php, xml, web-services, rest

I'm very new of PHP Web Services and I don't even know how to start programming a RESTFUL Web Service in PHP.

A bunch of years ago I created some sites in PHP, but as I can see, WS is pretty different and every tutorial is incomplete and needs of a basic PHP4 or PHP5 knowledge.

My basic RESTFUL PHP API must just:

1. Receive VIA POST two variables: variable1=value1&variable2=value2 and save them on a XML file on server.
2. if called a method /getXML it must send to the client the xml message which was first saved on a server file.

Can you suggest a clear scheme or pieces of code which manage this two requests and send the response to the client?

Comment: If you really want a REST api you should read up it first. You usually register api endpoints that follow the REST scheme. ie: GET /api/users.xml gives you all the users in xml, GET /api/users/1.xml gives you user with id 1 in xml, DELETE /api/users/1.xml deletes user with id 1, POST /api/users.xml creates a new user etc...

Comment: You don't need to save it as a XML file and you don't usually send an xml message, usually you send an json encoded message.

Comment: You can use PHP `SimpleXML`

Comment: Why are you guys all suggesting `XML`? RESTful API's should be designed to be fast, reliable and easy to use. JSON is becoming the data exchange format of choice because it aligns so well with those goals.

Comment: the problem is not the encoding (json or xml) but how to register enpoints and set all the api structure

Comment: Removed "thank you", improved formatting.